# How to answer "Where do you work?"

Tags: software-industry, united-kingdom

I have recently started working from home full time. When switching jobs, a lot of friends and family are sometimes interested what you're doing - they might ask where I work.

I usually have to say

> I work from home for Company X now

and it can be very awkward.

Is this a valid response? Is there something better I could be saying?

Comment: Does "where" really imply location instead of employer?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek I have found that it does sometimes imply both.

Comment: Don't worry too much, they're just making conversation, what you're saying is perfectly fine

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's well outside the scope of navigating a *workplace*.

Comment: Does it matter to the asker, that you work from home?  Does it matter to you, that you work from home?    "I'm working for Spacely Sprockets" is a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: What did you say before, when you didn't work from home?

Comment: @Brandin Previously, when working in another town I would say "I work for Company Y in Town B"

Comment: @LiamAllan not in this case its one of those wacky English word uses that doesn't follow exact rules

Answer (score 7):

The question usually refers to what's the name of the company you're working for, so you should lead with that.

Any geographical/home working information can come up in subsequent questions.

Comment: However, your current answer is fine; it does provide this info.

Answer (score 4):

> How to answer “Where do you work?”

Although the term used here is "where", what people really want to know is the name of the company that employs you, not where your desk is physically located.

Responding "I work for Company X" is the right way to start the conversation. Then you can talk about the role you hold, the kind of work you do, etc. If you choose to reveal that you work from home, you can do that too, or not - it's your choice.